# How to display ImageInput src in another component on react-admin?

Tags: react-admin

I'm using react-admin and I want to display the chosen image in another component.

I have already an image on my Edit screen. When I select a new one with ImageInput, I'd like to display it in my `<Poster />` component and change the existing image with a new one.

```
<Poster id="poster" {...props} source="card_image_path" 
label="resources.cards.fields.card_image_path" />

<ImageInput id="imageInput" source="images" accept="image/*">
  <ImageField source="src" title="title" />
</ImageInput>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you will be able to do it with the `<FormDataConsumer>` element. I've done something similar, showing the original image, except if a new image is selected, show that and hide the original.

```
<ImageInput source="contents" label="Billede" accept="image/*" mulitple={false}>
    <ImageField source="thumbnail" title="title" />
</ImageInput>

<FormDataConsumer>
   {({formData, dispatch, ...rest}) => {
       if (!formData.contents) {
            return (
                <Labeled label="Original image">
                    <ImageField source="thumbnail" {...rest}/>
                </Labeled>
            );
        }
    }}
</FormDataConsumer>
```

Answer (score 1):

Pass any component, but inside your custom component read the `record` props.

in this case `ImageInput` emits `src` as source

```
<ImageInput id="imageInput" source="images" accept="image/*">
<CustomComponent source="src" />
</ImageInput>
```

now `CustomComponent` will receive props.record

and then you simply read `const {src} = this.props.record;`