# How to pre populate the ImageField inside ImageInput in Edit Form, or the right approach to take

Tags: react-admin

I am working with react-admin and in the  functionality..  I need to display the original picture in an ImageField but if i choose to drag and drop a new picture then i need to update that ImageField with the new picture.  I can't seem to see any examples of what would seem to be a pretty common use case for Image related Edit functionality..

```
<ImageInput source="src" label="Product Image" accept="image/*" > 
        <ImageField source="imageUrl"/> 
</ImageInput>
```

Seems to be similar to this
[question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53590879/how-to-display-imageinput-src-in-another-component-on-react-admin/54716930#54716930)

but obviously i am new to this and after some frigging with it, i'm no closer to getting it to go...  The behaviour i would have expected i guess was that because imageUrl does exist on the form, that the ImageField above would already be populated with the existing pic when the form opened but it's not because it's inside the .. If anyone could point me in the right direction it would be a big help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have done it like this:

```
        <ImageInput source="src" label="Billede" accept="image/*" mulitple={false}>
            <ImageField source="thumbnail" title="title" />
        </ImageInput>

        <FormDataConsumer>
            {({formData, dispatch, ...rest}) => {
                if (!formData.src) {
                    return (
                        <div>
                        <Labeled label="Original image">
                            <ImageField source="thumbnail" {...rest}/>
                        </Labeled>
                        </div>
                    );
                }
            }}
        </FormDataConsumer>
```

This will display the original image, as long as no new image is selected. 
When a new image is selected, this will be displayed, and the original will be hidden.

Comment: Ok, i'll give this a shot.. just in the middle of spinning up a graphql server to replace a REST one to work with my react-admin project and then this issue will be back to the forefront!!

Comment: Top notch!!! Works like a charm, exactly what i was trying to accomplish.. Thanks a bunch

Comment: is this also problem or gap with Reference Inputs, i am having a wicked time trying to get them to act intuitively...  Would you happen to be able to shed any light on edit and add functionality with  ReferenceInput and ReferenceArrayInput?

Comment: @GregBelyea, try asking a new question, describing what you can't get to work and what you want to do. I might be able to answer, but others could also chip in.

Comment: I actually had posted the question then came back in to look at this one, meant to link it and didn't, it had been a very very long few days trying to get stuff working... I figured out all the issues i was having last night and today and will post the answers to them for anyone else who may struggle...  At the end of the day Redux Dev Tools is really my best friend now... Thanks for taking the time to respond to me, i appreciate it

Comment: @MadsLieJensen Thank you so much for this solution. Works perfectly! No i am going to understand how it's actually works :)